# TypeError: unstack() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fill_value'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I trying to use the [unstack()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) like`indicators.unstack(level=-1,fill_value='1')`,but it reports an error `"TypeError: unstack() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fill_value'"`. I'm trying to update the pandas to newest version and there's no change. Can someone help me with this? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: What is the output of `pip freeze | grep pandas` if you are on a *nix/Mac OSX based system, or `pip show pandas` on Windows. Pip has to be version `1.3+` though.

Comment: @CoryShay I'm a Mac OSX, it shows `pandas==0.18.0`.

Comment: What's the type of `indicators`?

Comment: @ayhan it's a dataframe

Comment: Please show the output of `pd.__version__`